# Add keys to an existing keyvault in azure using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-eventhub, azure-rm-template

Please i am getting the below error message upon sending the below ARM template to azure. what i am trying to do is to add key to an existing key vault on azure (under by subscription). The namespace provisioning should be in charge of storing the key in the Key Vault

**Error:**

```
05:12:00    "error": {
05:12:00      "message": "Encryption properties cannot be specified on creation of a namespace. They must be specified in a subsequent update. CorrelationId: dd69feae-5ba9-4c7e-9599-673493d31748",
05:12:00      "code": "BadRequest"
05:12:00    }
```

**Request body:**

```
 "resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
    "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
    "name": "[variables('eventHubNamespaceName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "identity":{
        "type":"SystemAssigned"
     },
    "sku": {
      "name": "[parameters('eventHubSku')]",
      "tier": "[parameters('eventHubSku')]",
      "capacity": 1
    },
    "properties": {
       "isAutoInflateEnabled": false,
       "maximumThroughputUnits": 0,
       "clusterArmId":"[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/clusters', parameters('eventHubName'))]",
         "encryption":{
           "keySource":"Microsoft.KeyVault",
           "keyVaultProperties":[
              {
                 "keyName":"[variables('eventHubNamespaceName')]",
                 "keyVaultUri":"[parameters('keyVaultUri')]"
              }
           ]
        }
  }
  },
  {
     "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), '/', variables('eventHubName'))]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "messageRetentionInDays": "[parameters('messageRetentionInDays')]",
      "partitionCount": "[parameters('partition_count')]"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to provision the Event Hub namespace **and also** set encryption properties in the same ARM template at the same time. Hence the error.

I would suggest performing these tasks in the following order:

1. First, create an Event Hubs namespace with a managed service identity.
2. Next, create a Key vault and grant the service identity access to the Key vault.
3. And then, update the Event Hubs namespace with the Key vault information (key/value).

A more detailed walkthrough is given in the [Event Hubs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/configure-customer-managed-key#use-resource-manager-template-to-enable-encryption) for the same.